# Fetch saved images in offline mode

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, offline-caching

I am working on a project, in which user can search images of different cities.

Let say, user has searched Delhi then the result should be saved so that next time when user search same city while having no internet connection then previously saved images should be shown(Delhi in this case).

Please suggest a good approach, confused between sqlite and cache

Answer (score 0):

If the images are above about 100k you should save them as a file and save the path to the file in the database. If they are around about 100k or less then you can save them as a byte array in the database.

SQLite itself does it's own caching, the around 100k boundary is based upon the findings as per [35% Faster Than The Filesystem](https://www.sqlite.org/fasterthanfs.html) (i.e. SQLite can be more efficient storing data as byte arrays (BLOBS)) and also the fact that there is a restriction upon the Cursor Window of 2M for Android, so if when extracting data from the database if a row exceeds this then a failure will result.

The difference between caching and SQlite is that SQLite is persisent i.e. the data is stored to disk. Caching is basically keeping data in memory, which is not persistent. However, SQLite does itself use caching. have a look at [PRAGMA schema.cache_size;](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_cache_size) .